# MIDI to MP3 from terminal: Accessing channel volume

Tags: bash, audio, midi, transcode

I'm writing a bash script that will be used to go through a ton of midi files and convert them into MP3s. Right now, I'm using `timidity` and `lame` for this, which works great:

```
timidity myMidiFile.midi -Ow -o - | lame - audioOutput.mp3"
```

However, I would like to have access to the different midi channels so that I can choose to lower or raise the volume on them individually. I've been looking through the [timidity manual](http://man.cx/timidity%281%29) without really finding any solution.

Can this be done via `timidity` or do I have to transition to some other program?

Comment: You could modify the MIDI files with some other program before converting them with Timidity.

Comment: @CL And do you have any suggestion of such a program? That is, for each MIDI file, I'm going to do a bunch of version of it, so it also needs to be an automatic process. I was thinking of maybe writing something in `Python` with the help of `python-midi`, but it feels like overkill if there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: Asking for tools is off-topic on SO. But if you were, e.g., using midish, you could ask specific questions about that.

Comment: @CL It is? Where would this question be on topic? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/? Thanks for the off-topic, indirect answer on my off-topic question by the way :)

Comment: Meta questions are on-topic on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).